# Accumulation of charge and potential difference across a resistor

Tags: electricity, charge, potential, electrical-resistance

If there is no accumulation of charge across a resistor, how can a potential difference (that is, potential drop) be created across it?

Answer (score 0):

There *is* an accumulation of (surface) charge on each side of a resistor in a circuit.

At the interface between the wire and resistor, the conductivity changes,
creating surface charge. This charge accumulation then establishes an electric field in the resistor.

Comment: I assume, too, that for a bendy piece of wire, AB,  carrying a current there is quite a complicated pattern of surface charges, in order that the electric field is everywhere  parallel to the wire and not simply in the direction $\vec {AB}$ or $\vec {BA}$.

Comment: Yes. that's an interesting  point too.